# Angular ui-router fails to load let alone resolve factory dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

UI router works fine as long as I'm not using **resolve**. I fail to understand the tricks. I would appreciate your help in understanding the problem. Following is the code.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
```

UI Router in action **[Not Working]** - Console doesn't print anything.

```
myApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('state1', {
        url: '/',
        resolve: {
            param1: function (RandomFactory) {
                console.log('test');
                return RandomFactory();
            }
        },
        controller: 'RandomController',
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
}]);
```

UI Router **[Working]** - Console prints.

```
myApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('state1', {
        url: '/',
        resolve: {
            param1: function () {
                console.log('test');
                return "hello";
            }
        },
        controller: 'RandomController',
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
}]);
```

Factory

```
myApp.factory('RandomFactory', ['', function () {
    return "Hello there";
}])
```

Controller

```
myApp.controller('RandomController', ['$scope', function ($scope, param1) {
    $scope.param = param1;
}]);
```

I've gone through the following posts.

1. [angular-ui router -- inherited resolved dependencies for NAMED dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747622/angular-ui-router-inherited-resolved-dependencies-for-named-dependencies)
2. [Angular ui-router fails to resolve named dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733119/angular-ui-router-fails-to-resolve-named-dependencies)
3. [Angular-ui-router: managing dependencies with resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618245/angular-ui-router-managing-dependencies-with-resolve)
4. [Promise dependency resolution order in angular ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983452/promise-dependency-resolution-order-in-angular-ui-router)

May be I'm missing something, but I've spent more than 5 hours on this.

Here is a fiddle for this - http://jsfiddle.net/kshitij/NPN7T/8/

---

Solution

> **Empty strings in the factory definition was the issue.** Though the framework should define an error for this case as it'll help new comers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please see here : http://plnkr.co/edit/cyZPh5h1lIYykqrh8Igh?p=preview

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.factory('RandomFactory', function () {
    return "Hello there";
});

myApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('state1', {
        url: '/state1',
        template:"<p>{{param1}}</p>",
        controller: function($scope,param1) {

            $scope.param1 = param1;

       },
        resolve: {
            param1: function (RandomFactory) {
                return RandomFactory;
            }
        }
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
}]);
```

you've few mistakes in factory definition it should be like  (remove empty string)

```
myApp.factory('RandomFactory', [function () {
    return "Hello there";
}])
```

and you should return RandomFactory instead of execute it when you resolving it

```
resolve: {
            param1: function (RandomFactory) {
                return RandomFactory;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, empty strings were the problem. Thanks. And error message would have saved my time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your `resolve` function in `state1` is not being invoked because you've given it a dependency to be injected (`RandomFactory`) that doesn't exist.

Why doesn't it exist? You've declared it in an incorrect manner using `['', function() {...}]`. If you don't want to inject any dependencies, just omit the first item of the array rather than using an empty string. Like this: `[function() {...}]`. It's too bad there isn't a nice error message but this seems to be why it's not working.

See here which works for me:

http://plnkr.co/edit/QYfMSV6zdBC0Ra2HiF2Z?p=preview

Comment: Maybe the down voter could describe why they thought this was a poor answer? It takes the author's code and makes a minor, reasonable adjustment and fixes the problem.

Comment: Yeah, empty strings were the problem. Thanks. And error message would have saved my time.